# $\int_0^\infty xf_X(x+m)dx$ for $X$ LogNormal

Tags: statistics

Is there an 'easy' way to see what the solution of $\int_0^\infty xf_X(x+m)dx$ is where $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma x}e^{-\frac{(\ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ is the density of $X \sim LogNormal$? or do I have to simply integrate it?

I know that $\mathbb E[X^k]=e^{k\mu+\frac{k^2\sigma^2}{2}}$ if that helps and $\int_0^\infty xf_X(x)dx=\mathbb E[X]$ of course

Comment: If you're looking for an `easy` way, then using a computer algebra system (CAS) will do so.  Using *Mathematica* the result is $m \left(\Phi \left(\frac{\log (m)-\mu }{\sigma }\right)-1\right)-e^{\mu +\frac{\sigma ^2}{2}} \left(\Phi \left(-\frac{\mu -\log (m)+\sigma ^2}{\sigma }\right)-1\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since, $f_X(x+m)$ is shifted, it is a shifted log-normal distribution. writing $x$ as $(x+m-m)$ will help but in the end it will boil down to calculations requiring you to manipulate shifted log normals. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152116/expectation-of-truncated-log-normal) will be helpful.